# US to Greece during Covid-19

Tags: usa, covid-19, greece

I bought a ticket with Turkish Airlines during February for early-July to travel to Greece from the US. The booking has since been cancelled over 4 times and I have rescheduled it for a later date each one. With my flight now being less than a week away, I am getting anxious over the EU restrictions.

I understand that US citizens are banned from entering Greece but if my flight doesn't get cancelled before its date (15 of July), will I be allowed to enter? If not, how? Will I be sent back, detained, or allowed to stay under restrictions?

I do not wish to reschedule my booking for personal reasons, although I understand that I should. If you can offer any insight on the situation described above, please do.

Comment: As tourists, US residents will probably not be allowed in the nearby future into the Schengen Area due to the present high level of new infections, that are many times higher than the European average. Where exceptions exist, such as students starting or resuming their studies, a quarantine is required. For further details see: [Travel to and from the EU during the pandemic | European Commission](https://ec.europa.eu/info/live-work-travel-eu/health/coronavirus-response/travel-and-transportation-during-coronavirus-pandemic/travel-and-eu-during-pandemic_en)

Answer (score 8):

It is not a matter of being allowed to enter. The airline will not allow you to board the flight in the first place, not even your US-TR flight. **You must reschedule or cancel your trip.**

Airline personnel do rudimentary document checks before you board, using a database called Timatic, which states directly

> Passengers are not allowed to enter.

except EU nationals.

As you know, EU and Schengen countries, of which Greece is both, have [banned entry](https://gr.usembassy.gov/wp-content/uploads/sites/206/Greek-Embassy-in-US-July-1.jpg) from third-country nationals effective July 1, 2020, except for diplomats and other extremely narrow categories. You have not stated your citizenship, but if you are not a citizen or permanent resident of an EU country, or a spouse or child thereof, the airline will not take any chances.

As it happens, [Turkey has re-opened](https://tr.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information-2/) to tourism, and has some comparable geography, climate, and classical sites, so you might consider that.

Comment: Isn't there a list of 15.or so countries whose nationals may visit for tourism starting on July 1st?  I know the US isn't on the list, so it won't change the situation for Lyn, but it's not true that all third-country nationals are banned.  Or did something change while I was blinking?

Comment: The EU recommendation as of July 1 was to allow citizens of Algeria, Australia, Canada, Georgia, Japan, Montenegro, Morocco, New Zealand, Rwanda, Serbia, South Korea, Thailand, Tunisia, and Uruguay, plus the People's Republic of China if they offer reciprocity. Each member state can still refuse admission, however.